# Accidentally run "apt install *" now all packages are marked as "manually installed"

Tags: apt, dpkg

I accidentally ran `apt install '*'`. Although it didn't install anything due to conflicts (e.g. multiple versions of `vim` editor), all installed packages lost their "automatic" property, which means I cannot enjoy APT's auto dependency check anymore. That is, if I remove `vim`, apt no longer prompts me to remove `vim-runtime`. I'm using a stripped down version of Advanced Packaging Tool, so `apt-mark` is not available. How can I restore the `automatic` property for those that are depended by another?

Note: I have `apt`, `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, `apt-config` and `apt-key` available.

Comment: `apt-mark` is a standard part of APT. What is available in your stripped-down version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives, the information about manual vs automatic installation is stored in `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`. There are no automatic backups and no logs. If you have a backup of that file, restore it.

If you don't have a backup, first make one in case you make up. Then, for each package, change the line `Auto-Installed: 0` to `Auto-Installed: 1` to mark the package as manually installed.

APT itself doesn't keep track of the dependencies of installed packages, that's done by dpkg. The information is in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` on Debian. Aptitude has an advanced search functionality that can operate on dependencies, but not apt. You can do some ad hoc parsing of `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. The following script (minimally tested) generates a list of packages that some installed package depends on:

```
</var/lib/dpkg/status awk '
    /^Package:/ {package=$2}
    /^Status:/ && $4 != "installed" {package=""}
    /^(Depends|Pre-Depends|Recommends|Suggests):/ && package != "" {
        sub(/^[^:]*: */, "");
        gsub(/ (\([^()]*\))/, "");
        split($0, dependencies, /[|, ]+/);
        for (d in dependencies) print dependencies[d]}
' | sort -u >dependencies.txt
```

Review that list, and maybe remove some lines that are packages which happen to be dependencies but that you know you'll want to keep even regardless. Then use this to tweak `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`:

```
</var/lib/apt/extended_states awk '
    BEGIN {
        while (getline <"dependencies.txt") auto[$0]=1;
        RS="";
    }
    $2 in auto {sub(/\nAuto-Installed: 0/, "\nAuto-Installed: 1")}
    {print $0 "\n"}
' >extended_states.new
```

Review the output file and move it into place if you're satisfied.

Comment: Wrong. There are automatic backups of `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` created by systemd's apt-daily.service. The backups are located at /var/backups (at least in default Ubuntu 20.04). Normally the file does not have lines `Auto-Installed: 0`. `Auto-Installed: 1` marks that the package is **automatically** installed. You can list dependencies of `<pkg>` by `apt-cache depends --installed <pkg>`; `apt-cache` is part of apt.